# Access foreign table column values in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is what i have and its working fine. I need to access a room's rate and multiply it with total_days to get the total cost. How do i access the Rates column pricing inside a method?

```
Booking belongs_to :room 
Room has_many :bookings, belongs_to :rate, 
Rate has_many :rooms

def calculate_days
   unless self.start_date.blank? || self.end_date.blank?
   self.total_days = self.end_date - self.start_date
   end
end
```

Comment: You can access from booking model like 
self.rate.rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the booking model, call `self.room.rate.pricing` to get the pricing. Then, you can get cost as:

```
def total_cost
  total_cost = self.room.rate.pricing * self.calculate_days
end
```

You also should handle the case where your calculate_days has blank start date or end date. Perhaps return 0 by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the table and search with "find" methods...

Here is a link to all finder methods

Here is an example of how to find a row by id "1".

```
Room.find(1)
```

Or you could search where booking_date = 2016-02-13

```
Room.where(booking: '2016-02-13')
```